# How to add Filter in JSGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsgrid

I'm using JSGrid and bring the data from a service to fill the table. Filter in the grid is not working. I've added `filtering: true` option but still it's not working. I've pasted a sample data and generated the same issue in the following code.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#grid").jsGrid({
    width: "100%",
    height: "400px",
    filtering: true,
    editing: true,
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    data: friends,
    fields: [
      { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 100 },
      { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
      countries,
      { name: "Cool", type: "checkbox", width: 40, title: "Is Cool", sorting: false },
      { type: "control" }
    ]
  })  
})

var friends = [
  {
    Name: "Ada Lovelace",
    Age: 36,
    Country: 3,
    Cool: true,
  },
  {
    Name: "Grace Hopper",
    Age: 85,
    Country: 1,
    Cool: true,
  },
  {
    Name: "Alan Turing",
    Age: 41,
    Country: 3,
    Cool: true,
  },
  {
    Name: "Miguel Alcubierre",
    Age: 53,
    Country: 5,
    Cool: true,
  }
];

var countries = {
  name: "Country",
  type: "select",
  items: [
    { Name: "", Id: 0 },
    { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
    { Name: "France", Id: 2 },
    { Name: "United Kingdom", Id: 3 },
    { Name: "Spain", Id: 4 },
    { Name: "Mexico", Id: 5 }
  ],
  valueField: "Id",
  textField: "Name"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using client side filtering, then it implemented in loadData method of controller.

Server-side apparently implemented with server script that receives filtering parameters, and uses them to fetch data, and pass to client.

That's why you can use client-side and server-side filtering at the same time.

Here is how your controller.loadData method could look like in this case:

```
loadData: function(filter) {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    // server-side filtering
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/items",
        data: filter,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(result) {
        // client-side filtering
        result = $.grep(result, function(item) {
             return item.SomeField === filter.SomeField;
        });

        d.resolve(result);
    })

    return d.promise();
}
```

hope this will help you to resolve you problem.